# React.js creating a table with a dynamic amount of rows with an editable column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, json, dynamic-tables

I am trying to create a react.js table that syncs with a leaflet map. I have this data and I am able to get the data properly, but I cannot create a table correctly. I am able to see the headers because they are hardcoded, but I am not able to see the rows. I also have a picture to explain the data at the console.log() points in the code. Here is the code:

```
/* Table React Component */
var TABLE_CONFIG = {
  sort: { column: "Zone", order: "desc" },
  columns: {
    col1: { name: "Zone", filterText: "", defaultSortOrder: "desc" },
    col2: { name: "Population", filterText: "", defaultSortOrder: "desc" }
  }
};

var Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    var tabledata = [];
    var length = _.size(testJSON.zones);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {

      var name = _.keys(testJSON.zones)[i];

      var population = testJSON.zones[name].population.value;
      if(name == "default") {
        population = testJSON.zones[name].population.default.value;
      }

      tabledata[i] = {name, population};
    }
    console.log(tabledata);
    return {zones: tabledata};
  },

  render: function() {
    var rows = [];
    this.state.zones.forEach(function(zone) {
        rows.push(<tr Population={zone.population} Zone={zone.name} />);
    }.bind(this));
    console.log(rows);
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Zone</th>
                    <th>Population</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>
      );
  }
});
```

Here you can see the `console.log(tabledata)` line in full as well as the first object in `console.log(rows)`

[image: Zone name and population]

I would like to see something like the picture below. Please note I want to Zone column to not be editable input, but the population to be editable:

[image: Desired Table]

Comment: Here is a fairly succinct example of creating a simple table component in React.  It helped me.   https://gist.github.com/ChaseWest/1935d08b156ae04b85d2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`<tr Population={zone.population} Zone={zone.name} />` does not seem like a valid React component to me. The lowercase `<tr>` indicates that this is not a custom component, but represents a standard HTML table row. `<tr>` elements require `<td>` or `<th>` elements inside them, for example:

```
var rows = [];
this.state.zones.forEach(function(zone) {
    rows.push(
      <tr />
        <td><SomePopulationComponent /></td>
        <td><SomeZoneComponent /></td>
      </tr>
    );
}.bind(this));
```

You could extract this into a custom element:

```
var CustomRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.Population}</td>
                <td>{this.props.Zone}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});

// ...

var rows = [];
this.state.zones.forEach(function(zone) {
    rows.push(<CustomRow Population={zone.population} Zone={zone.name} />);
}.bind(this));
```

Also, don't forget to give elements generated from inside a `map`/`foreach` function a `key` attribute.

Answer (score 10):

I have made this dynamic data table with dynamic rows and columns editable

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [
                {'id':1,1:'',2:'Class1',3:'Class2',4:'Class3',5:'Class4',6:'Class5',7:'Class6'},
                {'id':2,1:'MONDAY',2:'1',3:'2',4:'3',5:'4',6:'5',7:'6'},
                {'id':3,1:'TUESDAY',2:'1',3:'2',4:'3',5:'4',6:'5',7:'6'},
                {'id':4,1:'WEDNESDAY',2:'1',3:'2',4:'3',5:'4',6:'5',7:'6'},
                {'id':5,1:'THURSDAY',2:'1',3:'2',4:'3',5:'4',6:'5',7:'6'},
                {'id':6,1:'FRIDAY',2:'1',3:'2',4:'3',5:'4',6:'5',7:'6'}
            ],
            errorInput:''
        };

        this.submitStepSignupForm = this.submitStepSignupForm.bind(this);
        this.appendColumn = this.appendColumn.bind(this);
        // this.editColumn = this.editColumn.bind(this);
    }

    render(){

        let tableStyle = {
            align:"center"
        };

        let list = this.state.data.map(p =>{
            return (
                <tr className="grey2" key={p.id}>
                    {Object.keys(p).filter(k => k !== 'id').map(k => {
                        return (
                            <td className="grey1" key={p.id + '' + k}>
                                <div suppressContentEditableWarning="true" contentEditable="true" value={k} onInput={this.editColumn.bind(this,{p},{k})}>
                                    {p[k]}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        );
                    })}
                </tr>
            );
        });

        return (
            <fieldset className="step-4">
                <div className="heading">
                    <h3>Tell us about your schedule</h3>
                    <p>Dynamic Data Table by Rohan Arihant</p>
                </div>
                <div className="schedule padd-lr">
                    <table cellSpacing="3" id="mytable" style={tableStyle}>
                        <tbody>{list}</tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
           </fieldset>
        );
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/rohanarihant/pen/qmjKpj

Comment: DUDE! This is great! Exactly what I wanted.
Also, can you explain the `suppressContentEditableWarning="true" contentEditable="true"` tags and also your `editColumns()`

Comment: Legit god bless man. The only post that uses pure react + html and seems to work. And I believe those are parts of the tag for quite literally what they say: editing content.